# Is there any kind of statistical natural language processing library for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, nlp

Currently I'm reading Natural Language Processing for the Working Programmer (a work in progress book http://nlpwp.org/) and wondering if there is a decent library for statistical natural language processing tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a single library that does a lot of the tasks that statistical NLP library users would expect (*Warning: I don't know very much about statistical natural language processing*).  There are some interesting looking general-purpose core components like the NGrams, estimators, logfloat and hmm libraries.  There are also some tools that do some very specific tasks, like morfette for morphology or the hs-gizapp which wraps around GIZA++ for getting word alignments between pairs of documents

Keep an eye on the NLP section of Hackage and do consider joining the [Haskell NLP community](http://projects.haskell.org/nlp) (the site is currently down due to a recent attack on the haskell community server)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wanted to know if there are comprehensive snlp libraries, ok not as comprehensive as nltk for python. Before asking, I did some web search and I was a bit disappointed because of the short list of nlp tools on HackageDB.